# HTML from rawgithub.com encountering SecurityError "The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data"

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, cors

I'm checking out some old code I published to see if GitHub now allows me to run an HTML5 game directly via rawgithub.com (because SourceForge no longer appears to support this). The game is at:

http://rawgithub.com/bluemonkmn/iotaBuildIt/master/HTML/iotaBuildIt.html

What is it about the way rawgithub.com serves files that causes the same error that would occur when running files locally with the `file://` protocol? Is there an easy fix?

**Edit:**
I'm confused about the references to the term "cross-origin" here because the references to the image in the main page look like this:

```
<img id="CoolFont" style="display:none" src="CoolFont.png" />
<img id="FireFont" style="display:none" src="FireFont.png" />
<img id="Main" style="display:none" src="Main.png" />
<img id="NanoBots" style="display:none" src="NanoBots.png" />
```

So how can there possibly be a cross origin problem when I'm not even specifying a path let alone a different path from which to reference images?

**Edit 2:** It seems rawgithub has added an access mechanism that works better:
https://cdn.rawgit.com/bluemonkmn/iotaBuildIt/master/HTML/iotaBuildIt.html

Comment: A tainted canvas is nothing specific to the `file:` protocol, but to any cross-origin request. Can you please [post the code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125997/) with which you're drawing? Or at least link to a specific revision?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems since I last checked (years ago?) rawgithub has provided a new access mechanism that works better:

https://cdn.rawgit.com/bluemonkmn/iotaBuildIt/master/HTML/iotaBuildIt.html

Answer (score 2):

It's because they only proxy the JavaScript part as GitHub has a no-sniff header on it preventing scripts from working in the browsers.

For images they would have to provide access headers to allow cross-origin use. Cross-Origin means a different origin (made up of domain, protocol and port). Here it seem to not be the case so you cannot use images with canvas except from drawing them. The only origin they allow is (from their request header):

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:https://render.github.com
```

so unless your page is loaded from that origin you cannot fulfill the cors requirements for the images.

To make it work, move the image to a provider that allows cross-origin usage (for example ImgUr which offers free as well as paid services) or to your own provider where the page is hosted.

Then you need to request such use (if they are not in the same origin as your page) by specifying the `crossOrigin` property/attribute on the image before setting src:

```
img.crossOrigin = '';
img.src = url;
```

**Update**

If you see the headers from the request/response you can see that the images are *not* loaded from rawgithub.com but from (notice the contracted subdomain part **rawgithub**.com versus **raw.github**.com, the latter being a sub-domain of **github.com**):

```
https://raw.github.com/bluemonkmn/iotaBuildIt/master/HTML/CoolFont.png
```

[image]

---

and the referring page has origin:

---

[image: referring page]

---

As these are not the same origin you will get a cors error there. And as stated above, the access header does not allow any other domains than render.github.com so you cannot request such usage either.

The reason for this is probably because rawgithub (non-official GitHub site) acts as a proxy for some pages (ie. scripts, to avoid the `X-Content-Type-Options=nosniff` part of header which will return script as type text/plain which in turn prevent browsers to execute the scripts and use GitHub as a CDN) but not for others (ie. inline linking for images, as these are not related to script execution).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm confused about references to "cross-origin" here. As you can see in my new edit, my images should all be on the same origin as the HTML. Is there something I'm missing about the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header that means I can't use images even if they're on the same domain?

Comment: @BlueMonkMN I updated the answer. Hope it makes more sense now :)

Comment: Do you think rawgithub has good reason to skip proxying for images or could they maybe be persuaded to serve all content the same way to avoid this problem? Or could they be simply providing a different `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header? Or are they intentionally preventing this kind of access? The problem with using my own host is that the iotaBuildIt project kind of relies on people cloning their own version and serving it right up from source control.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN I don't know to be honest. I think their primary intent is to allow running script from raw.github (as GitHub allowed in the past). But since GitHub doesn't allow it anymore rawgithub came along to circumvent this for script. Not sure they had images in mind for this though (cors wise).